# « Vous l'avez vécu sur BFMTV »

Tags: sens

Aucun de [ces sens](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/vivre#vivre_1) ne semble être adéquat dans le contexte de la phrase d'au-dessus.

Si oui, qu'est-ce que *vivre* veut dire ici ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un emploi intransitif de *vivre*. Des sens donnés par le *Collins* que tu signales le plus proche serait le [2. (= ressentir)]

Je dirais que c'est plus proche d'*expérimenter / faire l'expérience de* que de *ressentir*.

C'est défini ainsi dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/vivre) :

> **B.** 1. Connaître, éprouver intimement par expérience subjective. *Vivre sa joie, ses amours. Quand on donne aux objets l'amitié qui convient, on n'ouvre pas l'armoire sans tressaillir un peu. Sous son bois roux, l'armoire est une très blanche amande. L'ouvrir, c'est vivre un événement de la blancheur* (Bachelard, *Poét. espace*, 1957, p. 85).

Glané au hasard sur le web :
-  [Endroit unique et dépaysant pour vivre une expérience à la ferme](http://www.giteetaubergedupassant.com/la-rabouillere-maison).
- [[ils] ont vécu la course en direct](http://www.letelegramme.fr/local/cotes-d-armor/rostrenen-loudeac/lacheze/plumieux/audrey-cordon-aux-jo-stress-emotion-puis-deception-31-07-2012-1791756.php).

Comment: I have a question for you: Did you edit my "Qu'est-ce que donc _vivre_ y veut dire?" because it was grammatically incorrect? What I meant to say is this: So what does _vivre_ mean here? (With "y" meaning "here," "in this context").

Comment: @User26328 Yes, sorry I edited it, I only meant it to help, in the perspective  depicted in [this Meta answer](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12/358). What you had written was perfectly understandable but it was not how a French person would say it. *Y* would not be used in this sentence. Can't explain just right  now (long...) but you might find the suitable answer in the [**y** tagged questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=y), if you don't then that'll be another question for you to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Second entry (transitive verb), 1 - b, in your Collins link.  "To go through." That is, *éprouver*, *traverser*, even *connaître*. (They associate it with « aventures », which can mean various kinds of things you undergo.)

> You experienced it on BFMTV.

English stations generally just say "saw" at this juncture, to remind you of the channel you're watching and implant the name in your head:

> You saw it on HBO.

The connotation can be positive or negative; you can also « vivre une souffrance » and so on.

P.S. I would say that Laure's reading of it being the transitive meaning #2 « ressentir » instead of 1 - b is also possible in this sentence. They're very close.

Comment: "Second entry (transitive verb), 1 - b" of what?

Comment: Your Collins dictionary link. Sorry, I'll edit that.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind and stupid, but I see no 1-b entry on that page...

Comment: When you scroll down past the first heading, "intransitive verb", you get to a second one — "transitive verb". The 1. there is divided into a. b. c.

Comment: Got it. I had seen it the fist time around as well, but the word "aventures" made me think it wasn't what I was looking for... Thank you for taking me out of my groping condition.

Comment: You're correct that English stations usually go with more literal (and more boring, imo) references to sight ("You saw it/You're watching it on ...") but, although not a slogan, the title of the old CBS radio, then TV show "You Were There" was pretty cool and came pretty close to matching BFMTV's creative notion of "You experienced it on ..."

Comment: Ah, nice example, @PapaPoule!

Answer (score 0):

Note:  this is strictly advertising speak.  Understand it, but don't use it!  Unless you're being sarcastic and trying to speak like an ad.

Comment: Well, the sentence is, but this meaning of *vivre* isn't.